# Install firefox addon programmatically

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions

I would like to either install firefox addons, specified by URLs or XPI files, to the currently active firefox profile programmatically, or at least to make them available (disabled, but listed in the extensions page).

What I've tried:

1. download xpi files to the `~/.mozilla/extensions/` directory
2. download xpi files to the `~/.mozilla/firefox/PROFILE/extensions/` directory

The addon does not appear in the list of available extensions

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried unzipping the .xpi (rename to .zip) to those folders?

> If you want to do a silent administrative install that immediately
> makes the extension available to limited users, you need to uncompress
> the .xpi file yourself (as a ZIP file) to an appropriately named
> (extension's ID) folder. On Linux/Unix platforms you can use a helper
> script to determine extension IDs in an automated fashion.

See here:

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Installing_extensions

and

https://askubuntu.com/questions/91925/unattended-install-of-firefox-extensions